# Http Post - long delay at state ExecuteRequestHandler

Tags: performance, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I have an asp.net mvc website hosted on Windows Server 2012r2 Standard which uses KnockoutJS to display data in a grid. This server is dedicated to the process that I'm having trouble with - it does not server any other requests.

An ajax call is made to a "GetRecords" action of a controller. This returns data for a couple of dozen records very quickly.

The user is able to make amendments to the data and submit for update. The knockout code makes another ajax call, this time posting the records. At this point the site "hangs" for a long time  (over 10 minutes), but it does complete successfully and the updated date is persisted to a database. During the "hang time" the CPU for the IIS Worker Processes hovers around the 50% mark.

I'm trying to figure out what's causing the delay. It seems that the delay happens before the first line of code of the controller action is reached. I've added trace statements to the action and I can see that once the 1st line is executed, then the action completes within a couple of seconds.

From the IIS manager, I've drilled in to "Worker Processes"\"Current Requests" during the time the page is "hung", I can see that the State is listed as "ExecuteRequestHandler" and the Module Name is "ManagedPipelineHandler". There are no other "Current Requests" displayed.

Using the Chrome dev tools, I've captured the json being posted for the update, it is approx 4mb in size.

I've ruled out the problem being caused by bandwidth because I've tested from a browser running locally (on the web server), and I get the same delay.

Also, when I post the same number of records on the same site hosted on my dev VM then it works fine - completes end-to-end in under 3 seconds.

Any suggestion on steps I can take to improve performance of the post?

I have created a process dump of the IIS worker process when it is in the "hanging" state, this is available at: [onedrive link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvzNxCpT1nhph8tQxC8ubYv-7FjOdg)

It seems that "Thread 28" is causing the issue, since this has a "Time spent in user mode" value of over 2 minutes. I requested the process dump about 2 minutes after making the http post request from the website. The post did eventually complete ok after about 20 minutes

Comment: The delay and high CPU usage indicates potential bugs in your ASP.NET MVC code. You have to follow tutorials like https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2008/02/22/net-debugging-demos-lab-4-high-cpu-hang/ to learn how to debug, or simply open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com for help.

Comment: The code in the controller is ok. The first line is a trace statement but this isn’t being called for several minutes after Chrome posts the request. I should also add that everything works great on my Dev VM, end-to-end is less than 3 seconds

Comment: I already said, debug it, or there is no way to know what's up. It is pointless to ask others to help you "guess" the cause.

Comment: Debug what? The delay is happening before it reaches the controller.

Comment: Have you even checked the blog post written by Tess? Have you even made a simple attempt to follow the steps? It would be useless to debug in VS and only your own code.

Comment: Sorry, I don’t understand the last sentence?

Comment: If your only debugging experience is using Visual Studio to step over your own code line by line, I am afraid that you wouldn't be able to effectively troubleshoot most of the crash/hang scenarios with IIS/ASP.NET. Tess wrote a series of posts showing the right ways to debug such, and that's why I asked you to follow. Don't expect you to understand everything, though.

Comment: @RobBowman Were you able to fix the issue? If yes, please share the solution or cause. Thanks

Comment: @MohsinMehmood I'm afraid the problem is not yet solved. I have now updated my question with a link to a proc dump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Able to work around this problem bypassing the MVC model binding. The view model param (editBatchVm) that was passed into the controller method has been replaced. So, instead of:

```
public void ResubmitRejectedVouchersAsNewBatch(EditBatchViewModel editBatchVm)
    {
```

I now have:

```
public void ResubmitRejectedVouchersAsNewBatch()
{
    string requestData = "";
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
    {
        requestData = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    EditBatchViewModel editBatchVm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EditBatchViewModel>(requestData);
```